# How to find lint rule that move '>' starting new lines to previous lines in html?

Tags: eslint, lint

I am having trouble formulating a question for Google, but I can illustrate my issue with an example:

This is the code fragment from my Vue component

```html
        <span v-if="item.editable">
          <v-icon color="primary" @click="openApplicantEditCreateDialog(item)"
            >mdi-pencil</v-icon
          >
          <v-icon color="primary" @click="openApplicantDeleteDialog(item)"
            >mdi-delete-forever</v-icon
          >
        </span>
```

And this is the code I need

```html
        <span v-if="item.editable">
          <v-icon color="primary" @click="openApplicantEditCreateDialog(item)">
            mdi-pencil
          </v-icon>
          <v-icon color="primary" @click="openApplicantDeleteDialog(item)">
            mdi-delete-forever
          </v-icon>
        </span>
```

I dislike the convention of starting new lines in components with `>`. Instead I prefer to end lines with the `>` closing HTML tags.

Comment: I finally found vue/html-closing-bracket-newline https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/html-closing-bracket-newline

Answer (score 0):

Proper plugin have name `vue/html-closing-bracket-newline`

https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/html-closing-bracket-newline

Description:

> Require or disallow a line break before tag's closing brackets

Example of usage

```html
<template>
  <!-- ✓ GOOD -->
  <div id="foo" class="bar">
  <div
    id="foo"
    class="bar"
  >

  <!-- ✗ BAD -->
  <div id="foo" class="bar"
  >
  <div
    id="foo"
    class="bar">
</template>
```